# How to generate javadoc with ant, for an existing project?

Tags: java, ant, build, javadoc

I want to make a Javadoc from an ant build file, but I don't see where it is.  In build.xml I have:

```
  <description>
    A sample build file for this project
  </description>

  <property name="source.dir" location="src"/>
  <property name="build.dir" location="bin"/>
  <property name="doc.dir" location="doc"/>
  <property name="main.class" value="proj1.Proj1"/>

  <target name="init" description="setup project directories">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${doc.dir}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile java sources">
    <javac srcdir="${source.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="run" description="run the project">
    <java dir="${build.dir}" classname="${main.class}" fork="yes">
        <arg line="${args}"/>
    </java>
  </target>

  <target name="clean" description="tidy up the workspace">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <delete dir="${doc.dir}"/>
    <delete>
      <fileset defaultexcludes="no" dir="${source.dir}" includes="**/*~"/>
    </delete>
  </target>

  <!-- Generate javadocs for current project into ${doc.dir} -->
  <target name="doc" depends="init" description="generate documentation">
    <javadoc sourcepath="${source.dir}" destdir="${doc.dir}"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

Where is the Javadoc located? Is it a hidden file or something placed in that directory?

Answer (score 18):

You have a `doc` target defined that generates javadoc in `${doc.dir}` which is set to `doc`.

```
  <!-- Generate javadocs for current project into ${doc.dir} -->
  <target name="doc" depends="init" description="generate documentation">
    <javadoc sourcepath="${source.dir}" destdir="${doc.dir}"/>
  </target>
```

So, to generate the javadoc just run:

```
$ ant doc
```

And you'll find it in the `doc` sub directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse, and your source files are under ${source.dir}/main, this works:

```
<target name="doc" depends="init" description="generate documentation">
<delete dir="${doc.dir}" />
<mkdir dir="${doc.dir}" />
    <javadoc destdir="${doc.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${source.dir}/main" />
    </javadoc>
</target>
```

Comment: BTW, it's better to put `<delete dir="${doc.dir}"/>` in `clean` section...